# Shell Script Removes Some of the Files

Tags: bash, shell, mv, file-management

I have a neural-network project for classifying flowers. I have a dataset of flowers and I want to rename for example all daisy images as daisy1, daisy2, and so on. I wrote a shell script in order to do that, but I noticed that every time I ran the script some of the images were lost and I don't understand why. Any idea? Here is my script:

```
(( i = 1 )) 

for file in $(ls)
do
[ "$file" != "change-filenames.sh" ] && mv "$file" "daisy$i" && (( i++ ))
done
```

Comment: That code renames any file which name is different than "change-filename.sh". I suspect that change-filename.sh is a script? You could want to test for the existence of the destination name before renaming. Take also a look at mmv(1).

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two risky issues in your code:

(1) You are using `ls` to generate a list of filenames (which would produce weird results if, for instance, a filename contains spaces).

(2) Say that your directory contains initially the files `abc` and `daisyabc1`. The first renaming would be a `mv abc daisyabc1`, hence destroying the original `daisyabc1`. The second renaming would then be a `mv daisyabc1 daisydaisyabc2`, and you would end up with only one file where you originally had two. I guess this is the cause of your loss of files.

BTW, your counter (`i`) does not get incremented if the `mv` fails. I don't know if this is a bug or is so by design.

Comment: Thanks. I'll add conditions to control undesirable results. Is there a more proper method to get filenames in a directory other than generating a list of filenames with ls? By the way it's by design.